# How do I increase cache size in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, cache

is there any way to increase the cache size of google chrome in ubuntu 11.10 so that frequently visited pages load faster, im using a very-slow internet connection so i badly need this

Comment: I'm going to stick my neck out here but I suspect that increasing the cache size over the default may not significantly improve things. What's more, pages often have fresh content and rotate ads thereby diminishing the utility of cache. You may have more luck in getting pages to "load" faster by blocking unnecessary items from downloading but that's another issue not relevant to askubuntu.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Absolutely. An easy fix to this is to add the following argument to the command.

```
chromium-browser --disk-cache-size=n
```

say `n` is 500000000 this would be 500 MB

You can check to make sure it increased it by typing the following in your browser and then looking at the Max Size value.

```
chrome://net-internals/#httpCache
```

Comment: Cf. <http://superuser.com/a/418591/65570> and the links there, which also mentions `--media-cache-size`.

Comment: As of Chrome (Linux) Version 80.0.3987.149 (Official Build) (64-bit), the net-internals link does not work: it returns this message: ``The net-internals events viewer and related functionality has been removed. Please use chrome://net-export to save netlogs and the external catapult netlog_viewer to view them.``

Answer (score 2):

Start chrome with the following option:

```
--disk-cache-size=n
```

Where `n` is the cache size limit in bytes.

Comment: Does this PERMANENTLY increase the Cache size or do i need to do this everytime i use chrome?

Comment: it's one time. if you want it permanentely edit you chrome launcher.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome now has two startup switches that you can use `--disk-cache-dir` and `--disk-cache-size`.

Simply close Chrome, right-click your Chrome shortcut, click Properties, and then in the field labeled "Target:", make it look something like this:

```
"...chrome.exe" --disk-cache-dir="CACHE_DIR" --disk-cache-size=N
```

Where `CACHE_DIR` is the new cache location, and `N` is the cache size limit, in bytes.

Use whichever switch you need, or both. Keep in mind, however, that these features may not be completely stable yet. But you probably shouldn't have any problem with using them.

And to anyone who's interested, I caught gander of the existence of these switches directly from a [source code file](http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src/chrome/common/chrome_switches.cc) for Chrome.

Comment: You should alter this for a sollution for Ubuntu not windows.

Comment: And a slightly more aesthetic presentation of switches can be found here: [List of Chromium Command Line Switches](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)

Comment: where is chrome shortcut? where is prpperties?